# throwing Argument Exception during manipulation of a bitmap

Tags: c#, bitmap

I have been trying to create a grayscale bitmap which it's pixels are filled by my own array of colors. This two dimensional array comes from a process that gets and manipulates every single pixel of an colored image. In other words i am trying to prepare a method to convert a colored one to it's grayscale.

**This is How i get the pixel's values and calculate the average**

```
for (var i = 0; i < SharedImg.ImgBitmap.Width;i++)
            {
                for (var j = 0; j < SharedImg.ImgBitmap.Height; j++)
                {
                    var pix= SharedImg.ImgBitmap.GetPixel(i, j);
                    var red = (int) pix.R;
                    var green = (int) pix.G;
                    var blue = (int) pix.B;
                    var avrg = (red + green + blue)/3;
                    var rgb = Color.FromArgb(avrg, avrg, avrg);
                    arrColors[i, j] = rgb;
                }
            }
```

**Now it fills the new bitmap with the array**

```
 var imgBitmap=new Bitmap(width,height,PixelFormat.Format16bppGrayScale);
            for(var i=0 ; i<width;i++)
                for (var j = 0; j < height; j++)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        imgBitmap.SetPixel(i, j, arrColors[i, j]);
                    }
                    catch (Exception exception)
                    {
                        mainForm.UpdateNewLine(new SystemResponse(){Color = Color.Red,State = exception.ToString()});
                    }
                }
```

When it reaches the `SetPixel` method it throws an `ArgumentException`.
Any idea or tip ?

Comment: What is the accompanying message with your exception?

Comment: @Dan-Cook > parameter is not valid (exception.Message)

Comment: Can you set a breakpoint and step through it to see which value(s) is causing your error

Comment: @Dan-Cook > Actually i did it. There is no abnormal value inside my array all of them are set between 0 to 255

Comment: Argument exception can be thrown from Color.FromArgb, I think you may be passing invalid parameters there after you do some division, have you checked those?

Comment: Lots of things wrong here, but it bombs because of the pixel format.  Use PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb instead.